# Replacing a value in an Excel column, based on its value in another sheet

Tags: sql, excel

I have a exported Excel sheet from SQL with records for insurance policies held by vendors that visit our office.  There are two separate tables that identify the Insurer and the Vendor by a code.  The table with the records of all the policies just has the codes for both of them.

Is there a formula that can look at another sheet for a value, and pull in another column from that sheet?  Basically there is a key code for each vendor, and I need to replace that code with their actual name from another excel sheet.

Or if there is a simpler way to do this in SQL I could try that too.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you can `JOIN` the tables together:

```
SELECT i.col1,i.col2,v.col1
FROM Insurer i
JOIN Vendor v
  ON i.key_code = v.key_code
```

Adjusting which columns you return as needed, without sample data it's unclear if there needs to be additional criteria in the `JOIN`.

In Excel you can use `VLOOUKUP()`, but I prefer `INDEX()` and `MATCH()`, below would try to match the value in `B1` to a value on Sheet2 in `B1:B20`, and return the value from the corresponding row from Sheet2 `A1:A20`:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$20,MATCH(B1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$20,0))
```

There are numerous illustrated examples of either excel method that will be easy to follow.